# TSQL & RegEx : incompatible for functions?

Tags: regex, t-sql

It's my first question here (sorry if I have a bad English, you know... French education...)

So, I had translate a C# easy program to a TSQL function and it was a little bit hard because TSQL is not a very open language. And after that, I must to recode my function with RegEx methods.

First, I think my code have already a kind of RegEx methods, and second, for the part where I want to remove the character's accents, I'd try a lot of methods (you can see that because some of these still be in my code on commentary) but I really do know how can I make a best method.

I can't use the COLLATE method because : "It's not a RegEx method" so...

Can I try something else or does my code is the most "RegEx" style what is possible for this language?

PS : Sorry, my variables and commentary are in French...

```js
USE [Analyse en Regex]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[Analyse_chaine_caratere]    Script Date: 06/28/2017 12:21:03 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Analyse_chaine_caratere] 
(
@vSaisie varchar(1000)--Nous prenons en paramètre la saisie de l'utilisateur
)
RETURNS varchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN

--Nous procédons à un sous fonction fastidieuse pour retirer les accents et ainsi faciliter l'analyse de la saisie

 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'À', 'a')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Á', 'a')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Â', 'a')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Ã', 'a')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Ä', 'a')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Å', 'a')

 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'à', 'a')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'á', 'a')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'â', 'a')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'ã', 'a')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'ä', 'a')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'å', 'a')

 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Ò', 'o')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Ó', 'o')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Ô', 'o')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Õ', 'o')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Ö', 'o')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Ø', 'o')

 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'ò', 'o')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'ó', 'o')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'ô', 'o')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'õ', 'o')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'ö', 'o')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'ø', 'o')

 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'È', 'e')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'É', 'e')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Ê', 'e')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Ë', 'e')

 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'é', 'e')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'è', 'e')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'ê', 'e')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'ë', 'e')

 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Ì', 'i')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Í', 'i')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Î', 'i')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Ï', 'i')

 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'ì', 'i')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'í', 'i')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'î', 'i')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'ï', 'i')

 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Ù', 'u')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Ú', 'u')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Û', 'u')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Ü', 'u')

 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'ù', 'u')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'ú', 'u')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'û', 'u')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'ü', 'u') 

 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'ÿ', 'y')

 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Ñ', 'n')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'ñ', 'n')

 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'Ç', 'c')
 SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie, 'ç', 'c')
 /* BEGIN    
    DECLARE @vRegexSansAccents varchar(1000) = '%[^a-zA-Z]%';
    DECLARE @iLongueurSaisie int;
    SELECT @iLongueurSaisie = LEN(@vSaisie); 
    WHILE @iLongueurSaisie > 0 
    BEGIN
        SET @iLongueurSaisie = @iLongueurSaisie - 1;
        IF (PATINDEX(@vRegexSansAccents,@vSaisie) > 0)
            BEGIN
                SELECT @vSaisie = STUFF(@vSaisie, PATINDEX(@vRegexSansAccents,@vSaisie),1,'');    
            END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            BREAK;
        END
    END  
   END */
  
      
   --SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie,'ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËéèêëÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÿÑñÇç','aaaaaaaaaaaaooooooooooooeeeeeeeeiiiiiiiiuuuuuuuuynncc')
   --SET @vSaisie = REPLACE(@vSaisie,'À|Á|Â|Ã|Ä|Å|à|á|â|ã|ä|å','a')
   
   SET @vSaisie = LOWER(@vSaisie) -- On passe la saisie en minuscule pour aller plus vite
  
--Nous déclarons nos variables
DECLARE @iCompteurVoyelle int
DECLARE @iCompteurConsonne int
DECLARE @iCompteurChiffre int
DECLARE @iCompteurCaractreSpecial int
DECLARE @iCompteurMot int
DECLARE @iCompteurAlphabetique int
DECLARE @iLongueurSaisie int
DECLARE @vResultat varchar(1000) -- Ce sera la synthèse de l'analyse de notre saisie

--On s'assure que les compteurs soient à zéro avant l'analyse
SET @iCompteurVoyelle=0
SET @iCompteurConsonne=0
SET @iCompteurChiffre=0
SET @iCompteurCaractreSpecial=0
SET @iCompteurMot=0

SET @iLongueurSaisie = LEN(@vSaisie)--On obtient le nombre de caractères contenus dans notre saisie

-- On extrait les voyelles de la saisie pour en faire une chaîne de caractère et sa longueur deviendra notre compteur voyelles
 BEGIN
      DECLARE @iLongueurTestVoyelle int,  @iVoyelles  smallint, @vSaisieVoyelles  varchar(1000), @vVoyellesCherches varchar(100)
      SELECT  @vSaisieVoyelles = N'', @iVoyelles = 0,  @iLongueurTestVoyelle =  DATALENGTH(@vSaisie)
      SET @vVoyellesCherches = 'aeiou'

      WHILE  @iVoyelles  <=  @iLongueurTestVoyelle
        BEGIN
          IF CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@vSaisie, @iVoyelles, 1), @vVoyellesCherches, 0) > 0
               SELECT  @vSaisieVoyelles = @vSaisieVoyelles + SUBSTRING(@vSaisie, @iVoyelles, 1)
          SELECT  @iVoyelles  =   @iVoyelles  + 1
        END 
     END    
    
    SET @iCompteurVoyelle = LEN(@vSaisieVoyelles)
    
    -- On extrait les consonnes de la saisie pour en faire une chaîne de caractère et sa longueur deviendra notre compteur consonnes
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @iLongueurTestConsonnes int,  @iConsonnes  smallint, @vSaisieConsonnes varchar(1000), @vConsonnesCherches varchar(100)
      SELECT  @vSaisieConsonnes = N'', @iConsonnes = 0,  @iLongueurTestConsonnes =  DATALENGTH(@vSaisie)
      SET @vConsonnesCherches = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz' 

      WHILE  @iConsonnes  <=  @iLongueurTestConsonnes
        BEGIN
          IF CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@vSaisie, @iConsonnes, 1), @vConsonnesCherches, 0) > 0
               SELECT  @vSaisieConsonnes = @vSaisieConsonnes + SUBSTRING(@vSaisie, @iConsonnes, 1)
          SELECT  @iConsonnes  =   @iConsonnes  + 1
        END 
     END    
    
    SET @iCompteurConsonne = LEN(@vSaisieConsonnes)
    
    SET @iCompteurAlphabetique = (@iCompteurConsonne+@iCompteurVoyelle)-- La logique veut qu'une lettre soit une voyelle ou une consonnes, de ce fait, la somme des voyelles et des consonne donne le nombre de caractères alphabétiques de la saisie
    
    -- On extrait les chiffres de la saisie pour en faire une chaîne de caractère et sa longueur deviendra notre compteur chiffre
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @iLongueurTestChiffres int,  @iChiffres smallint, @vSaisieChiffres  varchar(1000), @vChiffresCherches varchar(100)
      SELECT  @vSaisieChiffres = N'', @iChiffres = 0,  @iLongueurTestChiffres =  DATALENGTH(@vSaisie)
      SET @vChiffresCherches = '0123456789'

      WHILE  @iChiffres  <=  @iLongueurTestChiffres
        BEGIN
          IF CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@vSaisie, @iChiffres, 1), @vChiffresCherches, 0) > 0
               SELECT  @vSaisieChiffres = @vSaisieChiffres + SUBSTRING(@vSaisie, @iChiffres, 1)
          SELECT  @iChiffres  =   @iChiffres  + 1
        END 
     END    
    
    SET @iCompteurChiffre = LEN(@vSaisieChiffres)
    
    -- On extrait les caractères spéciaux (normalisés au clavier français, une prochaine version contiendra plus de caractères spéciaux à prendre en compte) de la saisie pour en faire une chaîne de caractère et sa longueur deviendra notre compteur caractère spécial
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @iLongueurTestCaracteresSpeciaux int,  @iCaracteresSpeciaux smallint, @vSaisieCaracteresSpeciaux  varchar(1000), @vCaracteresSpeciauxCherches varchar(100)
      SELECT  @vSaisieCaracteresSpeciaux = N'', @iCaracteresSpeciaux = 0,  @iLongueurTestCaracteresSpeciaux =  DATALENGTH(@vSaisie)
      SET @vCaracteresSpeciauxCherches = '.+-*/!:;?,<> ²&~"#''{([-|`_\^@)]=}%£$¤€µ§'

      WHILE  @iCaracteresSpeciaux  <=  @iLongueurTestCaracteresSpeciaux
        BEGIN
          IF CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@vSaisie, @iCaracteresSpeciaux, 1), @vCaracteresSpeciauxCherches, 0) > 0
               SELECT  @vSaisieCaracteresSpeciaux = @vSaisieCaracteresSpeciaux + SUBSTRING(@vSaisie, @iCaracteresSpeciaux, 1)
          SELECT  @iCaracteresSpeciaux  =   @iCaracteresSpeciaux  + 1
        END 
     END    
    
    SET @iCompteurCaractreSpecial = LEN(@vSaisieCaracteresSpeciaux)
    
    
    -- On utilise uen routine pour compter les mots
BEGIN
      DECLARE @cSplitteur varchar(10)
      -- Sauf si on en décide autrement, le "splitteur", à savoir le caractère qui brise la saisie en plusieurs mots, sera un espace, un retour à la ligne ou une tabulation
      SET @cSplitteur = ISNULL(@cSplitteur, SPACE(1)+char(9)+char(10))
      DECLARE @iPointeur smallint, @iFinDeSaisie smallint
      SELECT  @iPointeur = 1, @iCompteurMot = 0
      SELECT  @iFinDeSaisie = 1 + DATALENGTH(@vSaisie)/(CASE SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@vSaisie,'BaseType') WHEN 'nvarchar' THEN 2  ELSE 1 END) 

      WHILE CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@vSaisie, @iPointeur, 1), @cSplitteur, 1) > 0  and  @iFinDeSaisie > @iPointeur 
          SET @iPointeur = @iPointeur + 1

      IF @iPointeur < @iFinDeSaisie
         BEGIN
            SET @iCompteurMot = 1 
                               
            WHILE @iPointeur < @iFinDeSaisie
               BEGIN
                  IF @iPointeur +1 < @iFinDeSaisie and CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@vSaisie, @iPointeur, 1), @cSplitteur, 1) > 0 and CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@vSaisie, @iPointeur+1, 1), @cSplitteur, 1) = 0
                        SELECT @iCompteurMot = @iCompteurMot + 1, @iPointeur = @iPointeur + 1 
                  SET @iPointeur = @iPointeur + 1
               END
         END   
    END
    -- NOTE : Cette routine ne prends en compte que ce qui se trouve entre nos splitteurs. Elle considère un caractère spécial isolé tel que "!" ou un nombre comme un mot. Dans une prochaine version du programme, ce problème sera résolu.
    




SET @vResultat = 'Votre saisie comporte '+CONVERT(nvarchar,@iLongueurSaisie)+' caractères formant '+CONVERT(nvarchar,@iCompteurMot)+' mots. On y retrouve '+CONVERT(nvarchar,@iCompteurAlphabetique)+ ' caractères alphabétiques dont '+CONVERT(nvarchar,@iCompteurConsonne)+' consonnes et '+CONVERT(nvarchar,@iCompteurVoyelle)+' voyelles. Enfin, nous y trouvons '+CONVERT(nvarchar,@iCompteurChiffre)+' chiffres et '+CONVERT(nvarchar,@iCompteurCaractreSpecial)+' autres caractères spéciaux (espaces inclus) .' 

RETURN(@vResultat)
END
```

Comment: It is possible to use C# to extend T-SQL depending on the version of SQL Server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: You may want to look into `PATINDEX` and `STUFF` as well.

Comment: Hi,
I've already tried your both answers (PATINDEX and STUFF are on a comentary on my code because it was not a succes) and my old version of SQL Management Studio doesn't live me to use CLR.

So... My conclusion is my code is the "more optimised" for the reclamation what I've recieve.

Thank you ! ^^